# Transfer Google API Project ownership from an unreachable user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

We're using Google Analytics API in our application and perform actions (read data) on behalf of our users (we get their tokens via OAuth2). We use a *client id* and *client secret* to authorize our Google API project (application).

The problem is that we're unable to reach this project in Google's developer console, because the user in our Google App account who created this project was deleted. Regardless, the Google API still works (we have the key and the client secret) but we're unable to reach it in the admin section in the browser, but we can't access it because the owner was deleted.

What are the options to recover access to this API project? Is it possible to transfer ownership of this project using Google API? It's running in production so we can't afford to generate a new API project.

Is it perhaps possible to generate a new API project by keeping all our users consents (they authorize their accounts using an authorization popup in our web app)?

EDIT: it's also possible the user still exists, but we don't know who's the owner. Is it possible to retrieve this info using the app's api key/secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the account that has a credential was a gsuite user then we can transfer the project to the admin of the domain.

Have the admin of the GSuite contact me with information on the project, client id, email of the user who was deleted. We can then add the admin of the gSuite as the owner of the project.

From the question, this was likely a gsuite user because even after the account is deleted, the project was not deleted.

Comment: I messaged you on Twitter. Is that ok or should we try somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: Email introduction made good luck I would love to hear if you get it fixed.

Comment: Is there any other way to find the owner of a key we're using in production? I fear I may be in the same boat, but I'm not even sure who to reach out to…

Comment: You can use the client id to trigger the oauth approval page (through oauth playground or other ways) and on the approval page there is contact information about that developer. Also you can message me the client id and I can look up.

Answer (score 4):

How to find out who owns your credentials.

Authenticate your application the pop up window will appear.  Click on the name of the application the little arrow and a drop down will apear with the email address of the developer who owns the project.

[image]

If you have lost access to this account i am not aware of any way of getting access back.  However for the sake of curiosity i am going to contact someone at Google and find out if they have a procedure for account recovery or not.   I will update this when i hear back.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the account access has been lost. Appreciate your help, let me know what they say! Thanks!

Comment: I think hes west cost usa so it may be a while before i hear back.  If i don't update this in a few days feel free to add a comment it will ping me.

Comment: Any chance that this user was part of a gsuite account? Or is it a normal Google user?

Comment: It was a gsuite account, yes. Any options?

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/contact/ contact me I have someone at Google who may be able to help

Comment: I sent you a message via your contact form. Thanks!